# js dialog CLOSE attribute in the CSS

Tags: javascript, redirect, dialog, location

I have this html and js which I am including in all my webpages

```
<div id="dialog" title="MMS Message"></div>
<script>    
    function winAlert(msg) {
        $('#dialog').html(msg).dialog({
            resizable:true,    
            modal:true,
            hide: 'fade',           
            dialogClass: 'no-close dialog-dialog',
            close: function(event, ui) {
                        location.reload();
                    } //Reloads the Page
        });    
    } 
</script>
```

When I am trying to use this on UploadFunction.php page, the same page is getting executed time and again. So I tired the following but still it is not working

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                         $('#dialog').css({ 'close': 'self['location'].replace('uploadFIR.php')'});

                        //window.location = \"uploadFIR.php\"
                    </script>";
```

Comment: What do you meant by 'the same page is getting executed time and again' ?

Comment: `UploadFunction.php` is getting loaded again instead of `uploadFIR.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on UploadFunction.php page,

```
 $('#dialog').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
     window.location = 'uploadFIR.php';
 });
```

Comment: Nope your code is not working but this is `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function winAlert(msg) {
     $('#dialog').html(msg).dialog({ 
      resizable:true,     
      modal:true, 
      hide: 'fade',    
      dialogClass: 'no-close dialog-dialog', 
      close: function(event, ui) { 
         window.location = \"uploadFIR.php\"; 
        } //Reloads the Page 
     });     
    } 
    winAlert(\"Records from Selected Excel File have been successfully Imported.\");
    </script>";`